# Prevent PayPal payment by eCheck

Tags: paypal

Is there any way to prevent people paying by eCheck in a PayPal payment. They can be cancelled by the sender, or the payment can bounce, and I don't want to deal with it in my business logic.

I received my first eCheck payment today, and my code crashed, it was trying to parse the paypal response, and the field PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT was missing for some reason.

here is the response from paypal - not the bizarre check clear date 1969-12-31?

> {'PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE': ['expresscheckout'], 'ACK':
>   ['Success'], 'PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE': ['echeck'],
>   'PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE': ['None'], 'SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT':
>   ['false'], 'INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED': ['false'], 'CORRELATIONID':
>   ['ab29c03a5blah'], 'PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT': ['0.00'],
>   'PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID': ['3L382626CV22blahX'],
>   'PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK': ['Success'],
>   'PAYMENTINFO_0_EXPECTEDECHECKCLEARDATE': ['1969-12-31T16:00:00.000Z'],
>   'PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON': ['echeck'], 'PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT':
>   ['40.00'], 'PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY': ['Ineligible'],
>   'PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE': ['0'], 'TOKEN': ['EC-68T760256471blahE'],
>   'VERSION': ['124.0'], 'SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED': ['false'],
>   'PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS': ['Pending'],
>   'PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE': ['AUD'], 'TIMESTAMP':
>   ['2017-05-15T11:58:35Z'], 'PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID':
>   ['F4Q9blahblahS'], 'PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE':
>   ['None'], 'PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME': ['2017-05-15T11:58:35Z'],
>   'BUILD': ['33490117']}

Comment: The "weird" check clear date is a zero unix date (1 jan 1970) adjusted from UTC-8 (paypal's local time zone?) to UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember fixing this issue for reference transactions (`DoReferenceTransaction`) by adding `PAYMENTTYPE=InstantOnly`to the API request.

Based on PayPal's API reference I see that the `PAYMENTTYPE` parameter is supported in [`SetExpressCheckout`](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/set-express-checkout-nvp/) (as `L_PAYMENTTYPEn`)
and [`DoExpressCheckoutPayment`](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/do-express-checkout-payment-nvp/). I haven't looked at other express checkout operations.

In PayPal's new [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1), looks like you can set the `payment_mode` parameter to `INSTANT_TRANSFER`

Answer (score 1):

The e-Check payment can be disable if the transaction is coming from Website Payment Standard. This can be done from account setting

For Express Checkout, you may add PAYMENTINFO_n_PAYMENTTYPE = Instant

Further reference at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/